# MySQL in Python complaining about placeholders

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, placeholder, feedparser

I've been trying to use python's MySQLdb to execute SQL on a MySQL Database from SSH on my webhost. This program i wrote (on a mac) should print a table, but it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
import feedparser
import time
import MySQLdb

topnews = []
politics = []
# tech = []
sports = []
world = []
mostread = []
business = []

feeds = [topnews, mostread, politics, world, sports, business]
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews/.rss') #Just to keep other cells functioning.

def refresh():
    global d
    global topnews
    global politics
#     global tech
    global sports
    global world
    global mostread
    global business
    topnews = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews/.rss')
    politics = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/PoliticsNews/.rss')
#     tech = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews/.rss')
    sports = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews/.rss')
    world = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/worldNews/.rss')
    mostread = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/mostRead/.rss')
    business = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/businessNews/.rss')
    global feeds
    global d
    feeds = [topnews, mostread, politics, world, sports, business]
    d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews/.rss') #Just to keep other cells functioning.

refresh()


def summarize(feed, num): #Define a method called "summarize"

    summary = feed['entries'][num]['summary_detail']['value'] #Make a variable equal to the summary

    newsummary = "" #The summary we are trying to make, which is empty so far.

    for char in summary: #Keep running the following code as many times as there are characters in summary.

        if char == "<": #If the current character is a less than sign,

            return newsummary #We can finally show our new summary!  Mission Accomplished!!!!!!!

        else: #Otherwise,

            newsummary = newsummary + char #Add the current character to our new summary.

    return newsummary.replace(firstword(summarize(topnews, 0)), "").replace("- ", "")


def identify(feed):
    term = feed['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']
    if term == mostread['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "Most Read"
    elif term == topnews['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "Top News"
    elif term == politics['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "Politics"
#     elif term == tech['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
#         return "Tech"
    elif term == sports['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "Sports"
    elif term == world['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "World"
    elif term == business['entries'][0]['tags'][0]['term']:
        return "Business"

def firstword(string):
    word = ""
    for char in string:
        if char == "-":
            return word
        else:
            word = word + char

def cat(feed, num):
    spec = identify(feed)
    if firstword(summarize(feed, num)) != "(Reuters)":
        spec = spec + ", " + firstword(summarize(feed, num))
    return spec#.replace("(Reuters)")

def link(feed, num):
    return d['entries'][num]['link'] #Gives the link to the specified number article.

def date(feed):
    return d['entries'][0]['published']

#############################################################################################################################################  Coding Rocks!

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","databasename") # Of course, I included the actual values here.

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
cursor.execute('''
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news;
    ''')

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE news
    (
        id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        headline varchar(250) NOT NULL,
        summary varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
        date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        link varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
        imagelink varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
        category varchar(50) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
''')



for numelem in range( 0, len(mostread['entries']) - 1):
    sqlstring = '''
    insert into news (headline, summary, date, link, imagelink, category)
    values ("NULLFORNOW", %s, %s, %s, "NULLFORNOW", %s);

         ''' % (   summarize(mostread, numelem), date(mostread), link(mostread, numelem), cat(mostread, numelem)   )
    cursor.execute(sqlstring)

# cursor.execute('''
#     SELECT * FROM news;
#   ''') 


# results = cursor.fetchall()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

print "Whoopdeedoo! Program done. :)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

This throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feedparser.py", line 132, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sqlstring)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Brazil (Reuters) - Brazilian presidential candidate Eduardo Campos was killed in' at line 2")
```

I am sincerely sorry for the poor quality of this question; I am just too sick of this error, and I really don't know where the error is.

Please tell me where the problem is, and, of course, how to fix it.

Thank you, CJ

EDIT:
I tried @metatoaster's suggestion, and now I am getting the error:

`feedparser.py:137: Warning: Data truncated for column 'category' at row 1   cursor.execute(sqlstring, data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) you will see that the `execute` method calls for a separate data argument, not format the entire SQL statement using `%` as that will introduce errors into the SQL statement.  You can try this yourself by printing the `sqlstring` you generated and send it to MySQL and you *will* get that same error.  Do this instead, as per the documentation.

```
    data = (
        summarize(mostread, numelem),
        date(mostread),
        link(mostread, numelem),
        cat(mostread, numelem),
    )
    cursor.execute(sqlstring, data)
```

As for your second error, it means that the input data exceeded your length of the field (which you defined to a max of 50 characters). Again print out what you actually tried to input as category to see that it probably is too long of a string, or the wrong string even.

Comment: Thank you, so much! You are yet another person that is saving my life by relieving me of these crazy errors! THANKS A MILLION!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  You can do the same for yourself if you scrutinize the error and the line (and the surrounding lines for context) and compare it carefully with the examples in documentation, you too have the power to save your own life from these crazy errors.